# How to setup infinite scrolling with masonry?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tumblr

I recently ran into some problems trying to setup Infinite scroll on my tumblr with masonry. I found some code, and it worked perfectly on the demo website: http://www.jquery4u.com/demos/infinite-scrolling-demo1/ But on my tumblr only the Masonry part works, but not the infinite scrolling part. Here is my Javascript:

```
<script>
  $(function(){

    var $container = $('SECTION');

    $container.imagesLoaded(function () {
            $container.masonry({
                itemSelector: '.item',
                columnWidth: '.item',
                isFitWidth: true
            });
        });

    $container.infinitescroll({
      navSelector  : '#page-nav',    // selector for the paged navigation
      nextSelector : '#nextPage',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
      itemSelector : '.item',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
      loading: {
          finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
          img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif'
        }
      },
      // trigger Masonry as a callback
      function( newElements ) {
        // hide new items while they are loading
        var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
        // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
        $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
          // show elems now they're ready
          $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
          msnry.appended( $newElems );
        });
      }
    );
  });
</script>
```

Here is the html for the next Page link:

```
{block:Pagination}
<nav id="page-nav">
    {block:NextPage}
        <a style="color:red;" id="nextPage" href="{NextPage}">Next</a>
    {/block:NextPage}
</nav>
{/block:Pagination}
```

I do already have the Masonry, ImageLoaded, and Infinite Scrolling scripts linked. As I said, The masonry works fine, but the infinite scroll seems to be doing nothing at all. The next link is also working too, since I tested it and it does take me to the next page. But again the Infinite scrolling does nothing whatsoever. If anyone could help it would be very appreciated, or if you have any other suggestions or alternatives, that would also be nice.

Comment: So how are you loading more images?

Comment: With the infinite scroll plugin, it's supposed to automatically load the next page when you scroll to the bottom of the page, like this example: http://www.jquery4u.com/demos/infinite-scrolling-demo1/ But for some reason it's not doing that, even though it's using virtually the same code.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell without a demo link, but looking at the example you used for reference:

```
msnry.appended( $newElems );
```

There should throw an error saying `undefined`. This is due to `msnry.appended`.

The line should  be:

```
$container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
```

Source: http://www.jquery4u.com/demos/infinite-scrolling-demo1/